# How ro get the value of a tag/element from an XML Response?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, file-get-contents

I'm creating a PHP script that would get the value of  tag/element from an xml response. Here's the URL that gives the response: http://stageapi.myprepaid.co.za/Api/ConsumerRegisterRequest/21b6e114-010a-e311-a672-00155d4905d3

If you're trying to access the URL on the browser, you'll get an XML file, but when using file_get_contents() The format of the xml changes. The xml becomes somewhat like:

```
{"ID":"e5d1b161-110a-e311-a672-00155d4905d3","Email":null,"Mobile":null,"Password":null,"MeterNumber":"1234567890","Bank":"ABSA","CampaignID":"1040","WebBrowserIdentifierString":null,"Status":"Pending...
```

Do you have other ways on how to get the XML and preserving its format? So that I could use SimpleXMLElement.

Thanks!

Comment: I think its better to use json format, you can just use `json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true)` to get that output as an array

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: That format is JSON, not XML. look at http://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The script is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with browser's headers. That should help you to have the same format as you need.

Comment: You mean using Content-Type: text/xml or Content-Type: application/xml? I've tried but still gives me the the output I've posted above.

Comment: @maikelsabido I mean send browser name, version, etc. Do you need an example?

Comment: No, it's okay. The script is working well now. I just forgot to use json_decode since the output is in JSON format. Thanks for your help, anyway.